# Using titleformat, "frame" is supposed to result as "hang", but in a box (numbers followed by text)

Tags: titlesec, framed

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame] % was display
{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\vspace*{-2cm}
\leavevmode\leaders\vrule height7pt width3pt depth0pt%
\hfill\kern1pt\chaptername\hspace{3.6pt}\thechapter\kern8pt%
\leaders\vrule height7pt width3pt depth0pt\hfill}
{8pt} % was 3pt
{\vspace*{-5pt}\hrule\vspace{6pt}}
[\vspace{2pt}\hrule\vspace{1cm}] % draws line under box

\newcommand\Bheadfont{\fontsize{12pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}[frame] % was hang
{\normalfont\sc\color{darkblue}\Large}
{\thesection\hskip0.618em\Bheadfont}
{3pt}{}[]

\titleformat{\subsection}[frame] %
{\normalfont\sc\color{darkblue}}
{\thesubsection\hskip0.618em}
{3pt}{}[]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a framed chapter}

\section{This is a framed section}

\subsection{This is a framed sub section}

\end{document}
```

The title `hang` gives this kind of result:

> 2.3 - solving linear equations

I would like to use frame but keep the numbers and the text in-line.
The icing on the cake would be a coloured frame with coloured fill; is that possible?
I want to avoid `\fcolorbox` and `\fbox` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `framed` package. As it defines only framed  or shaded (but not both) environments, I define an `frshaded*` environments, which you can easily customise, choosing frame width, frame separation from contents, frame colour and fill colour. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Thistle3!30!}
\colorlet{framecolor}{PaleVioletRed3}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}

\newenvironment{frshaded*}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] %
{\color{PaleVioletRed4}\normalfont\Large\sffamily\bfseries\FrameSep 20pt\FrameRule=3pt}
{}
{0pt} % was 3pt
{\begin{frshaded*}\chaptername\hspace{3.6pt}\thechapter\kern8pt#1\end{frshaded*}\vskip-0.8ex\color{framecolor} \titlerule[1.2pt]}


\newcommand\Bheadfont{\fontsize{12pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\section}[hang] %
{\normalfont\scshape\color{darkblue}\Large\colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSteelBlue2!25!}\colorlet{framecolor}{darkblue} \FrameRule=1pt}
{}
{0pt}{\begin{frshaded*}\thesection\hskip0.618em\Bheadfont#1\end{frshaded*}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang] %
{\normalfont\scshape\color{darkblue}\colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSteelBlue2!25!}\colorlet{framecolor}{darkblue} \FrameRule=1pt\FrameSep=6pt}
{}
{0pt}{\begin{frshaded*}\thesubsection\hskip0.618em#1\end{frshaded*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is a framed chapter}

\section{This is a framed section}

\subsection{This is a framed sub section}

\end{document}
```

[image]